# XSL transformation outputting multiple times and other confusion

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm attempting to transform a section of an XML document (which is *mostly* HTML) with a templated piece of markup should a particular pattern be matched. I'm inexperienced with XSLT (I've only used xpath, really) and online documentation is sparse so I'm struggling with it...

To the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="dff6df70-e454-11e4-0e5f-978e959e1c97" />
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="fee5c268-1675-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689" />
            <h4>China urbanisation</h4>
            <br />
            <em>1.8m</em>
            <br />
            ...
        </li>
        <li>
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="0023edbc-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689" />
            <h4>Ebola crisis</h4>
            <br />
            <em>$1bn</em>
            <br />
            ...
        </li>
        <li>
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="015961e4-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689" />
            <h4>Fighting inequality</h4>
            <br />
            <em>$479m</em>
            <br />
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
```

I am attempting to apply this transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="//ul/li/content[../h4][../em]">
        <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
            <xsl:for-each select="../../li">
                <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="content" />
                    <div class="breakout__item-content">
                        <header>
                            <h3 class="breakout__item-headline"><xsl:value-of select="h4" /></h3>
                            <p class="breakout__item-subheading"><xsl:value-of select="em" /></p>
                        </header>
                        <p class="breakout__item-description"><xsl:value-of select="text()[normalize-space()]" /></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result:

```
    ...
    ...


            <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="fee5c268-1675-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">China urbanisation</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">1.8m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="0023edbc-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Ebola crisis</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$1bn</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="015961e4-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Fighting inequality</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$479m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
            China urbanisation

            1.8m

            ...


            <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="fee5c268-1675-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">China urbanisation</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">1.8m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="0023edbc-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Ebola crisis</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$1bn</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="015961e4-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Fighting inequality</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$479m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
            Ebola crisis

            $1bn

            ...


            <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="fee5c268-1675-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">China urbanisation</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">1.8m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="0023edbc-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Ebola crisis</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$1bn</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
        <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="015961e4-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
        <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
                <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Fighting inequality</h3>
                <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$479m</p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
            ...
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
            Fighting inequality

            $479m

            ...


    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I cannot make any sense of this for two reasons:

1. Why has the generated template been output in full 3 times?
2. Why has the text content been copied over to the result document but not the existing tag structure?

Any help answering the above and nudges in the right direction are appreciated.

EDIT: This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="dff6df70-e454-11e4-0e5f-978e959e1c97" />
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
        <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="fee5c268-1675-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
            <div class="breakout__item-content">
                <header>
                    <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">China urbanisation</h3>
                    <p class="breakout__item-subheading">1.8m</p>
                </header>
                <p class="breakout__item-description">
                ...
            </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="0023edbc-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
            <div class="breakout__item-content">
                <header>
                    <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Ebola crisis</h3>
                    <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$1bn</p>
                </header>
                <p class="breakout__item-description">
                ...
            </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
            <content type="ontology/content/ImageSet" url="015961e4-1676-11e5-1ef3-978e959e1689"/>
            <div class="breakout__item-content">
                <header>
                    <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">Fighting inequality</h3>
                    <p class="breakout__item-subheading">$479m</p>
                </header>
                <p class="breakout__item-description">
                ...
            </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the expected output corresponding to the example input you gave?

Comment: I've updated the question with what I'm trying to do =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your template is applied to 3 elements, and for each of them, loops over all the parents `li` elements (yes, for each of them, ask all the `li` elements, children of the grand-father of the current `content`, which are all the 3 `li` elements, each time).

2) Because that's what the default template rules do to the nodes you do not match.  Processing starts at the document node, recurses over all elements recursively, whilst text nodes not matched are copied to the output tree, until some of the `content` elements are matched by your explicit template rule.

The following, probably, solves those 2 problems (by applying template only to those selected `content` elements, and for each of them by using only its own `li` parent element):

```
<xsl:template match="/body">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="ul/li[h4][em]/content"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
   <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
      <xsl:for-each select="..">
      ...
```

**EDIT**: Given your edit, with the expected output, here is something a bit more complete (see explanations above for the differences with yours).  The first template copies everything by default, the second one tells that for `li` elements containing a `content` element, there is something different to do:

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li[content]">
   <ul class="breakout o-grid-row">
      <li class="breakout__item" data-o-grid-colspan="12 M6 L3" role="group">
         <xsl:copy-of select="content"/>
         <div class="breakout__item-content">
            <header>
               <h3 class="breakout__item-headline">
                  <xsl:value-of select="h4"/>
               </h3>
               <p class="breakout__item-subheading">
                  <xsl:value-of select="em"/>
               </p>
            </header>
            <p class="breakout__item-description">
               <!-- not sure what you want here, so I kept the normalize-space -->
               <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </p>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Applied to your example input, it gives your example output.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really useful explanation.

Comment: You posted the example output in the meantime, so I've just edited my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Wow, thank you - again super helpful. One issue though (sorry!) and that's a nested list, so we have `<ul><ul class="...">`. You've saved me so much time already so don't sweat too much ;-)

Comment: .. I've worked around this by applying the template to all `<ul>` elements and adding a condition inside. Again, thanks!